# display specific popup box when hovering over different elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm a beginner in html css js and I have created an `iteractive map` of some greek islands . What I am trying to do is when I move my mouse on an island I want to display a pop up box with  some info about the island . I can position hidden pop up boxes manually above each island but it seems like a very slow way . In my code below I use the `<map>` and `<area>` tags to spot each island on the map .

My code(12 greek islands located on an image ):

```html
<div id = "map-container">
  <img src = "IMAGES/island-map.jpg" id="map" usemap="#islandmap">
  <map name="islandmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="65,54,152,97" id="Patmos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="167,39,264,98" id="Lipsi">
    <area shape="rect" coords="70,166,121,186" id="Kalimnos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="216,153,279,198" id="Leros">
    <area shape="rect" coords="240,216,316,241" id="Kos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="265,278,288,300" id="Nisiros">
    <area shape="rect" coords="754,418,853,451" id="Kastelorizo">
    <area shape="rect" coords="192,611,238,646" id="Kasos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="41,257,130,313" id="Astipalaia">
    <area shape="rect" coords="255,491,294,633" id="Karpathos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="406,339,508,490" id="Rodos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="305,378,389,406" id="Chalki">
    <area shape="rect" coords="405,270,454,315" id="Simi">
    <area shape="rect" coords="301,317,366,358" id="Tilos">
  </map>
</div>
```

CSS (cursor is pointer when you hover over an island ):

```css
map area:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My web page with the image :

[image]

So the problem is how to display a pop up box using javascript above each island when I hover over one without positioning hidden pop up boxes manually on my page . I am not allowed to use jquery since this is a university project . I would appreciate your help with this .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: Please inlcude **islandmap image** corrrect image

Comment: please include image @VASILEIOS SKENTOS

Answer (score 1):

## Please try this ...

How to use **Tooltipster**

**Steps**

---

1. Add library of Tooltipster

```
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

2. Add relevent `JS` for tooltipster

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.tooltip').tooltipster({});
  });
```

3. Then add **class** and **title**.

```
    class="tooltip" title="Patmos"
```

Try this Snippet

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({});
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id = "map-container">
  <img src = "https://www.dreamingreece.com/sites/default/files/dreamingreece_dream_in_greece_dodecanese_dodecanisa_dodekanisa_map_xartis_greece_ellada_greek_islands.jpg" id="map" usemap="#islandmap">
  
  <map name="islandmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="65,54,152,97" title="Patmos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="167,39,264,98" title="Lipsi" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="70,166,121,186" title="Kalimnos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="216,153,279,198" title="Leros" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="240,216,316,241" title="Kos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="265,278,288,300" title="Nisiros" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="754,418,853,451" title="Kastelorizo" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="192,611,238,646" title="Kasos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="41,257,130,313" title="Astipalaia" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="255,491,294,633" title="Karpathos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="406,339,508,490" title="Rodos" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="305,378,389,406" title="Chalki" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="405,270,454,315" title="Simi" href="#" class="tooltip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="301,317,366,358" title="Tilos" href="#" class="tooltip">
  </map>
</div>
```

### **For more example**

Use `popover()` function.

`data-content` value to be shown in **popup**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger : 'hover',
        placement : 'top',
    });   
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="mx-auto text-center">
  <h1>The map and area elements</h1>
  <p>Hover on the computer, the phone, or the cup of coffee to show popover.</p>

  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" class="img-fluid w-100">
 
  <map name="workmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" data-content="Computer" data-toggle="popover">
    <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" data-content="Phone" data-toggle="popover">
    <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Cup of coffee">
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: It's on this site https://www.dreamingreece.com/el/dodekanisa if you scroll a little . I have made my background same color as the image like a complete map . I cannot use JQUERY for this project

Comment: Can i use javascipt @VASILEIOS SKENTOS

Comment: I have not written the js yet . Yes js should be used . I will continue it later . Thank you very much for your solution if you have an idea to use for js feel free to write it

Comment: **JQuery** is best for this. Javascript make complex code. Plesae check this snippets @VASILEIOS SKENTOS. And  ensure you reached in your goal.

Comment: I cannot use Jquery . I am not allowed .